# I am using windows 8. Ctrl and Alt keys not working

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, capslock, numlock

I use Windows 8 and suddenly today the Ctrl and Alt keys have stopped working. I can also see that Caps Lock and Num Lock button lights are also not working.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried unplugging and plugging the keyboard back in? What about another keyboard?

Comment: Have you tried using the keyboard on a different machine? Is it a hardware, or a software issue?

Comment: Have you restarted your computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [onscreen keyboard](https://superuser.com/questions/608117/enable-windows-8-on-screen-keyboard-on-desktop-pc), included by Microsoft, and [demonstrated here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/type-with-the-on-screen-keyboard). Does that work? If not, you have a software problem with Windows or an app interfering with Windows.

If the onsscreen keyboard {Alt} and {Ctrl} do work, do a Shutdown of your PC, unplug the keyboard and then plug it back in, and retry it. Should your keyboard still be recalcitrant, then replace it.

.

And, when you find an answer, click on the checkmark at the left, to show others it worked. That also boosts the cred of the person who provided you an answer, which helps them.